# How to install Charm-crypto library for python3 on windows 10?

Tags: python, charm-crypto

I've installed GMP 5.x , PBC (latest) and OPENSSL but when I try `pip3 install charm-crypto this error occurs. If anyone knows how to solve this error because I don't understand it please tell me? By the way the error is much longer than this but I couldn't paste it, It is mostly repeating the process of copying

```
(venv) C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\Testing>pip3 install charm-crypto
Collecting charm-crypto
  Using cached Charm-Crypto-0.43.tar.gz (364 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages (from charm-crypto) (50.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=1.5.5 in c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\lib\site-packages (from charm-crypto) (2.4.7)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for charm-crypto, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: charm-crypto
    Running setup.py install for charm-crypto ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\
\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-83yi7s_w\\charm-crypto\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-83yi7s_w\\charm-crypto\\setup.py'"
'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vq3a6qkl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users
\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\include\site\python3.9\charm-crypto'
         cwd: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-83yi7s_w\charm-crypto\
    Complete output (194 lines):
    Platform: Windows
    Config file: config.mk
    Warning, using default config vaules.
    You probably want to run ./configure.sh first.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm
    copying charm\config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm
    copying charm\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\core
    copying charm\core\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\core
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\core\crypto
    copying charm\core\crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\core\crypto
    copying charm\adapters\abenc_adapt_hybrid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\adapters
    copying charm\adapters\dabenc_adapt_hybrid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\adapters
    copying charm\adapters\ibenc_adapt_hybrid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\adapters
    copying charm\adapters\ibenc_adapt_identityhash.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\adapters
    copying charm\adapters\kpabenc_adapt_hybrid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\adapters
    copying charm\adapters\pkenc_adapt_bchk05.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\adapters
    copying charm\adapters\pkenc_adapt_chk04.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\adapters
    copying charm\adapters\pkenc_adapt_hybrid.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\adapters
    copying charm\adapters\pksig_adapt_naor01.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\adapters
    copying charm\adapters\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\charm\adapters
    running build_ext
    building 'charm.core.math.pairing' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\charm
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\charm\core
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\charm\core\benchmark
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\charm\core\math
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\charm\core\math\pairing
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\charm\core\utilities
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DBENCHMARK_E
NABLED=1 -Icharm/core/utilities/ -Icharm/core/benchmark/ -Ic:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3
9\include -IC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\
ATLMFC\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10
.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Fi
les (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tccharm/core/benchmark/benchmarkmodule.c
 /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\charm/core/benchmark/benchmarkmodule.obj
    benchmarkmodule.c
    C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-83yi7s_w\charm-crypto\charm\core\benchmark\benchmarkmodule.h(12): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier
 includeÿ: 'sys/time.h'ÿ: No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit cod
e 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0]
= '"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-83yi7s_w\\charm-crypto\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8
3yi7s_w\\charm-crypto\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(c
ode, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-vq3a6qkl\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --co
mpile --install-headers 'c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\testing\venv\include\site\python3.9\charm-crypto' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please copy-paste in the full error, don't post a image that's cut in half.

Comment: @AKX I pasted it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there is file with code which is not compatible with MSVC. sys/time.h is included in benchmarkmodule.h and unfortunately this file does not exit in MSVC.

Try to install mingw, set the CC to mingw compiler and  run the pip3 command . If it still not working you can try to build it directly like explained in https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/install_source.html.

In all cases you will need a mingw compiler. However, it may be complicated.
You will need to install the msvc redistributable. When you run the make command, f you face the error `Unknown MS Compiler version 1927`. modify the `cygwinccompiler.py` file by adding :

```
#custom add
elif msc_ver == '1927':
    # VS2019 / MSVC 16.7
    return ['msvcr100'] 
#custom add
```

before the last add.
You may also need to add a file `distutils.cfg` like explained in https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers. Once these modifications done, the compilation should start normally.

Perhaps the easiest would be to compile it under linux.

Comment: Where should I write the build process? I didn't understand which path I have to choose in the Command prompt (Cmd) to use the ' configure ' and ' make ' commands?

Comment: If you are trying to build the like explained in the install_source , it will be easier with the msys terminal (mingw terminal). You need to download the package yourself extract it and you will find the configure in the base directory.

Comment: When I write the command in the msys terminal it tell me:  (sh: ./configure: No such file or directory) and (make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.)

Comment: The easiest way is to extract charm-dev in the home directory of msys (pwd to know where it is exactly). Then `cd charm-dev` and then you can run the configure in this directory.

Comment: Isn't pwd a Unix command coz I'm using windows 10? I searched for the charm-dev but I didn't find it where it should be usually located?

Comment: with msys you can use linux like commands. the github of charm-crypto https://github.com/JHUISI/charm

Comment: I extracted it but it still tells me 'No such file or directory' when I use 'cd charm-dev'

Comment: when you exract it what is the folder name? It is weird but if you have an other name you can enter to this folder

Comment: did you copied the folder to the home direcorty os msys? if no you have to give the path to this folder

Comment: I copied it and it worked now thank you. But when I entered the 'make' command, this error appeared:  "c:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 84, in get_msvcr
    raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)
ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1927
make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: Seems like a configure error. Did you give the good target when you did the configure. The error is speaking about ms complier while you need a mingw one.

Comment: I think that I gave the good target, maybe I did something wrong and didn't notice, I'm not an expert in these configurations thing. I installed Microsoft visual studio before cz i needed the build tools C\C++ for python can that be a reason of this error?

Comment: Like i told you before, i dont think you can compile this librarie with Ms compiler. So you have to configure it to ise mingw compiler which have support of sys/time.h or modify this code to make it windows friendly.  Also be careful when you ibstall mingw it can be tricky (by default it dont install a lot of things)

Comment: Okay , how to make it use mingw as a compiler instead of Ms ?

Comment: Normally , you dont ave to do anything if you are using the good shell. however there in an option `cc` you can use to choose a compiler. take a look also in the config.log and config.mk to see what compiler you are using

Comment: my in fact it's not your fault. it is python which looks for the MSVC runtime library Mingw32CCompiler-> CygwinCCompiler-> get_msvcr.

the comment present in this function is: Include the appropriate MSVC runtime library if Python was built with MSVC 7.0 or later.

Comment: This is somehow complicated. Would it be easier to use Ubuntu instead of Windows?

Comment: I think it will be the easiest way.I did not suggest it because I did not know if you have a linux (ubuntu)

Comment: I don't but I'm ready to install it after losing all this time on this error. I really can't thank you enough for your help

Comment: You are welcome. if you think that the answer has brought you something or can bring something for the future you can validate it or upvote it .

Comment: If you want to compile it in an ubuntu. you can use a VM.